# z-index, positioning elements absolute

Tags: css

I'm developing a responsive site and I have an issue that I've never tought I could have It xD

I have an image inside a div wrapper... and just want to put an icon font with :after selector when that wrapper/img has one class...

Trouble comes on z-index, for z-index works I need to "absolute" that img, but if I do that wrapper's height not contains img... and I can not put my :after element relative to img or wrapper well

I have this issue here: http://codepen.io/MrViSiOn/pen/VYpedg

```css
   * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   div {
     float: left;
     width: 24%;
     height: auto;
     margin-right: 1em;
     border: 1px solid blue;
     padding: 1em;
     position: relative;
     overflow: visible;
   }
   img {
     max-width: 100%;
     border-radius: 50%;
     padding: 15px;
     border: 1px solid #aaa;
     z-index: 10;
     position: absolute;
   }
   div:after {
     content: "\e60c";
     position: absolute;
     color: #234;
     font-family: "Nubelo";
     bottom: 0;
     left: 45%;
     font-size: 2em;
     z-index: 1;
   }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://i.icomoon.io/public/temp/d53e6aab62/Nubelo/style.css">
<div>
  <img src="http://assets.worldwildlife.org/photos/2090/images/hero_small/Sumatran-Tiger-Hero.jpg?1345559303" />
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://assets.worldwildlife.org/photos/2090/images/hero_small/Sumatran-Tiger-Hero.jpg?1345559303" />
</div>
```

Thank you, If you need more information, just tell

Comment: could you place this into a bit more context? Or draw out what you want it to *end up* like.

Comment: You can use position:relative to enable z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Thanky you Marcel Burkhard...

I didn't know that using position:relative enables z-index.

That's the answer!